# How to make a python string slicing clone function?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, slice

I'm making a library for strings with ansi formatting, and for implementing slicing properly i need a function like this:
`slicer(start, stop, step, string)` that should return the same output as `string[start:stop:sep]`, but without using `string[start:stop:step]` (`string[i]` is allowed), it also needs to handle negative values for `start`,`stop`, and  `step` same way as string slicing do.

This is the code i got so far, the parts with # [?] are the parts that i'm not sure how to handle

```py
def slicer(start, stop, step, string):
    if step == 0:
        raise ValueError("Step can't be 0")
    if step is None:
        step = 1

    if step > 0:
        if start is None:
            start = 0
        elif start < 0:
            # Ex:
            # if s = "hello world"
            # s[-4:] is the same as
            # s[7:]
            start += len(string)
            if start < 0:
                start = 0
        if stop is None:
            stop = len(string)
        elif stop < 0:
            stop += len(string)
            if stop < 0:
                stop = len(string)
    # Negative step
    else:
        if start is None:
            start = len(string) - 1
        elif start < 0:
            start += len(string)
            if start < 0:
                # [?]
        if stop is None:
            # [?]
        elif stop < 0:
            stop += len(string)
            if stop < 0:
                # [?]

    n = ""
    for i in range(start, stop, step):
        n += string[i]
    return n
```

Something that confuses me related to what the default value for `stop` should be when `step` is negative:
for example,
`s = "hello world"`
consider `s[0::-1]`, that is just the inverse of the string, `dlrow olleh`,
now, how do i write this without ommiting the stop value?, i.e. `s[0:?:-1]`.

if you try 0 you get

`s[0:0:-1]` --> `"dlrow olle"`, it's missing the 'h'.

if you try 1 you get

`s[0:1:-1]` --> `"dlrow oll"`, it's missing the 'eh'.

if you try -1 you get

`print(s[0:-1:-1]) --> ""`, it's an empty string

Comment: "and for implementing slicing properly i need a function like this: slicer(start, stop, step, string) that should return the same output as string[start:stop:sep], but without using string[start:stop:step]" - why not just slice the string?

Comment: "Something that confuses me related to what the default value for stop should be when step is negative" - all your function's arguments are mandatory. You don't have to worry about defaults.

Comment: strings with ansi have stuff like \033[91;1m in the middle of them, which should not be considered as part of the string when slicing, because of this the object structure used for the library needs a function like this

Comment: @user2357112, this function is just a simpler example that needs the same logic, on the actual code it is actually the __getitem__ dunder method of a class, where i need to handle defaults.

Comment: Can you afford just picking some unused UTF8 codepoints to represent ANSI escape sequences? There are quite a few of them, and with such simplification you'll have just a plain string, easy to use and implemented in underlying C (so fast). When converting to "real" string representation, just replace those codepoints with corresponding escape sequences.

Comment: If you need to keep current solution, you can remove all this logic entirely and use `slice(start, stop, end).indices(your_string_length)` - this will be a 3-tuple `(normalized_start, normalized_end, step)` such that start and end components are `>= 0` and step remains unchanged.

Comment: (and `'hello'[0::-1]` is `'h'`, not `'olleh'`. If you want reversed string, it's `'hello'[::-1]` equivalent to `'hello'[None:None:-1]` or `'hello'[-1::-1]` and nothing else unless you know the string length, it's expanded form will be `'hello'[-1:-len('hello')-1:-1]`)

Comment: @STerliakov slice.indices works perfectly, if you want you can post as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice.indices` method ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices)) to obtain "normalized" indices matching those used by builtin objects. Given three range parameters (non-negative, negative or `None`) and a sequence length, you can obtain three numbers (with non-negative `start` and `end`) using

```py
def slicer(start, stop, step, string):
    start, stop, step = slice(start, stop, step).indices(len(string))
    ...
```

In your case, consider passing string first and providing defaults for slice parameters, because `step` is used not very often, so your method will be more convenient with default `step=1` or `step=None` (both are equivalent).

If you plan to use it for `__getitem__` implementation, you'll be already given a `slice` object, so can just call `.indices` on it directly.